# ArcGIS Addin Localization Not working?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, add-in, xml, internationalization, french

I want to have a localized (e.g. French) addin toolbar. What I have done so far:

1. Created the Config.fr-FR.xml file and put all the translations there
2. Changed my system "Region and Language" setting and set the format to **French (France)**
3. Installed the Addin

When I run Arcmap, I don't see the localization (I see the original english version)

Note: I have also read [this page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000002s5000000) completely

Can anybody tell me where the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show localized resources properly, the user must change "**Display Language**" of the operating system.

In windows 7:

Region and Language Dialog > Keyboards and Languages > Install/Unistall languages

The other preferred solution is to change the config.esriaddin file directly, rather that creating localized versions.